# Conditional logic on a Reactor Flux

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am a Reactor newbie. I am trying to develop the following application logic:

1. Read messages from a Kafka topic `source`.
2. Transform the massages.
3. Write a subset of the transformed messages to a new Kafka topic `target`.
4. Explicitly acknowledge the reading operation for all the messages originally read from topic `source`.

The only solution I found is to rewrite the above business logic as it follows.

1. Read messages from a Kafka topic `source`.
2. Transform the massages.
3. Immediately acknowledge the message not be written to topic `target`.
4. Filter all the above messages.
5. Write the rest of the transformed messages to the new Kafka topic `target`.
6. Explicitly acknowledge the reading operation for these messages

The code implementing the second logic is the following:

```
receiver.receive()
        .flatMap(this::processMessage)
        .map(this::acknowledgeMessagesNotToWriteInKafka)
        .filter(this::isMessageToWriteInKafka)
        .as(this::sendToKafka)
        .doOnNext(r -> r.correlationMetadata().acknowledge());
```

Clearly, `receiver` type is `KafkaReceiver`, and method `sendToKafka` uses a `KafkaSender`. One of the things I don't like is that I am using a `map` to acknowledge some messages.

Is there any better solution to implement the original logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not *exactly* your four business logic steps, but I think it's a little bit closer to what you want.

You could acknowledge the "discarded" messages that won't be written in [`.doOnDiscard`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnDiscard-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Consumer-) after `.filter`...

```java
receiver.receive()
        .flatMap(this::processMessage)
        .filter(this::isMessageToWriteInKafka)
        .doOnDiscard(ReceiverRecord.class, record -> record.receiverOffset().acknowledge())
        .as(this::sendToKafka)
        .doOnNext(r -> r.correlationMetadata().acknowledge());
```

Note: you'll need to use the proper object type that was discarded.  I don't know what type of object the Publisher returned from `processMessage` emits, but I assume you can get the `ReceiverRecord` or `ReceiverOffset` from it in order to acknowledge it.

Alternatively, you could combine `filter`/`doOnDiscard` into a single [`.handle`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#handle-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) operator...

```java
receiver.receive()
        .flatMap(this::processMessage)
        .handle((m, sink) -> {
            if (isMessageToWriteInKafka(m)) {
                sink.next(m);
            } else {
                m.getReceiverRecord().getReceiverOffset().acknowledge();
            }
        })
        .as(this::sendToKafka)
        .doOnNext(r -> r.correlationMetadata().acknowledge());
```

Comment: This example not only answer the question but also clarifies  the use of handle method, sink and onDiscard  better that  documentation...